# Spree: How to add blog entries to home page using Blogging Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a site in development that has Blogging Spree working.

Here's Blogging Spree:

https://github.com/stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree

Currently, I have a link to the blog section in the navigation bar, but I want to include a few blog entries on the home page of the site. Do I need to include the controllers into the application controller to do so? How should I go about doing this?

I'd also like to include the images uploaded to the blog entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this the following way:

Clone project from github and put it directly to root of your application.

On your Gemfile

Change

```
gem 'spree_blogging_spree', github: 'stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree'
```

To:

```
gem 'spree_blogging_spree', path: 'spree_blogging_spree'
```

Now you can have it locally and can modify it to your liking.

I would add another model inside extension to handle image uploads and reuse Image model that Spree has built in, which uses paperclip, do `bundle open spree` to investigate inner workings of Spree.

Also if you're new to Spree/Rails, this is a lot of work and not going to be easy! good luck and hope my comment helps.

Comment: Also... yes, I'm obviously pretty new to spree and rails, but it's been a fun, but difficult, journey thus far.

Comment: Understanding spree can be pretty hard at first but you'll get the hang of it as long as you keep at it

Comment: Would be awesome if you can up vote if my answer helped you in any way